# Is ther open source tool for calculating Getis-O-ord (ARCGIS) and able to customize in own platform

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis

i would like to know is there any open source tool for calculating Getis-O-ord(ArcGIS)? If so can i customize for own application or can i write my script within that application like qgis.

Comment: it is available in R : http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/index.html

Comment: [CrimeStat](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/CrimeStat/) might be a solution too.

Comment: thank you radek. Actually i dont know R language and scripting in R.so i tried with crimestat.Is plotting of cluster is possible in crimestat? i have loaded crimestat but i am not able to see any plotting option. I have loaded events data and seen the statistics but not able to plot it and visualize it. is is possible with crimestat.